# Rules in Drupal 7: EntityMalformedException in custom PHP

Tags: rules

I used to run successfully the following custom PHP code in rules before a node is stored

```
$update_node = node_load($node->nid);
$lat1 = floatval($node->field_geo["und"][0]["lat"]);
//SOME MATH HERE
$update_node->field_winkel_dorf["und"][0] = array("value"=>$winkel);
node_save($update_node);
}
```

But now after a major update of lots of modules I get this error:
EntityMalformedException: Fehlende Paketeigenschaft auf einem Element des Types node. in entity_extract_ids() (Zeile 7663 von /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/includes/common.inc).

I have no idea what changed....

Any help very very welcome.

Comment: why are you using node_save before node stored?

Comment: hhmmm... I have no idea. I actually don't really understand whats happening there but it used to work very well. 

But it seems the problem lies in th node_load command, sice I can't print_r($update_node);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the first line `$update_node = node_load($node->nid);` because `nid` does not exist yet in node object then remove the last line as well `node_save($update_node);`.

Also, replace each `$update_node` variable with `$node` which is available by rules module.

Your final code should look like the following:

```
$lat1 = floatval($node->field_geo["und"][0]["lat"]);
//SOME MATH HERE
$node->field_winkel_dorf["und"][0] = array("value"=>$winkel);
```